# How to make stealthier armor?

Tags: medieval, armors, stealth

In my setting a colonial power at a late medieval level of technology has gifted its native allies with mail armor. The natives are quite happy to receive it, but are simultaneously frustrated. The problem is that their style of warfare is based around ambushes and night raids, so the war leaders are displeased with how it catches the light and the clinking sound of moving chain. How then can the native warriors modify the mail armor so as to reduce noise and reflective quality?

Comment: if your chainmail is shiny your not taking care of it. mail should be coated in wax or oil to keep it from rusting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You don't need to camouflage it, use it as it is

Your question is not necessarily the one your natives will ask themselves. The more interesting question they'd ponder on is "How can we incorporate this new tool into our battle strategies?". This includes hiding the shine and adding cushion pads to it, but this goes far, far beyond this.

The colonial powers supposedly gave their strongest asset, and it's not a sneaky one simply because it's not part of their war culture. You on the other side already have designed the best tools at disposal for ambush tactics, you don't necessarily need more on that side. What you want then is not to force this mail armor into your mindset, but to use it in your sneaky-stabby strategy as a whole.

Ok, then what do we do? In general, assymmetric warfare like guerillas require an excellent ability at predicting the movement of opposing parties to strike heavily and minimize losses. To solve this part, use mail armor as a bait like a worm on a fishing hook. It's catchy, it makes this unit a threat to be recognized and a pain to take down. Now that you can direct the attention of enemy troops, you can set all kinds of trap on the path towards it, calling back your mail soldiers as the enemy nears on them. And if you think the other general caught on this trick, just put ambushes where they'd go to counter this trick. In short, with this new pivot point on the battlefield, you can more easily take control of the pace and space of the fight, and play how you want to play.

**N.B. :** In case all your traps failed, you now still have a last resort option. Indeed, remember that battles revolve around taking (out) goals, some of which can't be moved easily (villages...). At some point you might need to earn time to move these objectives away from the enemy's paws or prepare new ambushes. Adding mail armors to the rearguard could really help you hold them off while you save the important assets and regroup. Truly, your colonialist made a great gift!

Comment: This answer could come right out of the U.S. Marine warfighting doctrine. Pit your strength against their weakness. Be flexible. Exploit gaps. And, evidently: do not fight Tortliena.

Answer (score 3):

- Cover it with a thin layer of cloth or leather, much like [brigandine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brigandine) armor.
- Cover it with dirty grease.

Answer (score 2):

They don't have to do anything for noise. There's actually a video by Metatron discussing this very issue:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fVCS_iatpXw

Short summary: when walking or sneaking, mail essentially makes no more noise than what you'd make by moving normally. It makes a bit more noise if you're running or jumping around, but not as much as you'd think.

As for dulling it, you could use a matte paint of some sort, but the easiest method is simply to wear some sort of light cloth over the mail.

Comment: If you want to make metal non-shiny, you can always blue the steel -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluing_(steel)

Answer (score 1):

**The natives do not intend to use it to make war.**

If you are sneaking around you don't need armor.  You catch your enemy by surprise and kill them before they fight back.  Then you chuckle to your ninja brethren using sign language before sneakily killing more enemies.

Your ninjas do not want fair fights in war, because fair fights are dumb and their way of doing it works fine.  Your people are going to use the armor to play sports!  Their favorite sports involve lots of hitting opponents over the head, gut punches and kicks to the crotch.  Previously players would just wear padding in those areas.  Players got hurt a lot which the crowd loved but it was hard to finish a game.

Now with the mail players can really unload with full swing bashes to the head and groin kicks that lift armored opponents off their feet! That gets the crowd roaring, and the armored player so kicked can scramble back into action.  The mail also makes an awesome sound when hit.  It is like a demolition derby which is what the crowd really wanted to see all along.

Comment: I guess that now it's the hands that need padding x); I'm not sure it's healthy to punch iron mail barehanded for a living.

Comment: @Tortliena - they have huge armored boxing gloves for those punchings.  Also many different types of mummified and frozen dead animals they use as clubs.